# Comment after fragile \end{frame} breaks beamer

Tags: beamer, comments

Today I spent more time than I would like to acknowledge being beaten by a comment in the code...

I was trying to insert some verbatim in a presentation and was getting this error:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
```

Then, reducing the whole thing to a MWE I got this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
Hello :)
\end{frame}% NO :(

\end{document}
```

and the error persisted.

Then, when I removed the comment after the `\end{frame}` the whole thing worked.

Can someone explain what happens here?

---

Disclaimer: no, I don't need the comment there :P

Comment: That's a common problem when grabbing things to be treated verbatim as long as you want to do more than the original `verbatim` environment: verbatim mode is still in force when `\end{frame}` is scanned, because basically the input is examined line by line.

Comment: @egreg But even without verbatim? The example does not have verbatim and it doesn't work...

Comment: `fragile` frames are grabbed verbatim for saving them in an auxiliary file to be read back in.

Comment: @egreg I found a .vrb file that contains `Hello :)
\end{frame}% NO :(
\end{document}`, so I presume that beamer searches for a line with *exactly*  `\end{frame}`. Am I correct?

Comment: I guess this is the reason. Indeed, if you try `\end {frame}`, the error is the same.

Comment: Oh man I came across this today, took me have an hour to figure out what's going wrong!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging a little in `beamer`'s innards I found the answer to be, as egreg pointed out, the verbatim processor.

For `[fragile]` frames, `beamer` uses its verbatim processor, located in `beamerbaseverbatim.sty`. Beamer has a neat verbatim processor:

```
\protected\long\gdef\beamer@processframeline#1^^M{%
  \edef\beamer@test{\beamer@strip@whitespace#1\beamer@strip@stop}%
  \ifx\beamer@test\beamer@stopframe%
    \let\next=\beamer@framewritten%
  \else%
    \immediate\write\beamer@verbatimfileout{#1}%
    \let\next=\beamer@processframeline%
  \fi%
  \next%
}%
```

The processor is a delimited macro that will read everything up to a carriage return character (new line). The read content is stored in `\beamer@test` and compared to `\beamer@stopframe` which is, most of the time, defined as:

```
\xdef\beamer@stopframe{\string\\end\string\{frame\string\}}
```

which expands to the exact string `\` `e` `n` `d` `{` `f` `r` `a` `m` `e` `}`.

The processor compares `\beamer@test` with `\beamer@stopframe` and if they are different the content of `\beamer@test` is written to `\beamer@verbatimfileout` (the .vrb file) and the `\next` macro is `\let` to be the processor, and it recursively calls itself to continue reading. Otherwise, if `\beamer@test` is the string `\end{frame}`, the processor exits normally.

The error happens because the processor does not ignore comments (they may be required in verbatim contexts!), so the processor compares `\end{frame}` with `\end{frame}% NO :(`, which obviously fails, and keeps reading past the `\end{frame}`.

Two things can happen now:

First, this is the last frame, so the processor will never find a matching `\end{frame}` and the `! File ended while scanning use of \next.` error will appear and the compilation stops.

Second and more painful, there is another frame which will have the <s>droids</s> `\end{frame}` the processor was looking for. But in this case, the `\next` will be `\let` to `\beamer@framewritten`, which essentially reads the content of the .vrb file back to the frame. But the contents will be something like:

```
Hello :)
\end{frame}% NO :(
\begin{frame}
Hello again!
```

which will make things go wild :)

### TL;DR

Remember kids, when using `[fragile]` frames, the `\end{frame}` **must** be the **only** thing in the line. <s>No leading spaces nor comments allowed (trailing spaces are gobbled by TeX).</s>

As samcarter noted in her comment, the current version of Beamer allows leading *and* trailing whitespaces and tabs. The `\beamer@strip@whitespace` macro will eat spaces and tabs before the comparison with `\beamer@stopframe`.

Comment: Leading spaces and tabs are allowed since some time.

Comment: @samcarter Indeed! My version of texlive is a little outdated... I'll update my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: This was fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/0c387deb21263aff6bc4864618e3cb74dcf32357