# Fragile and newenvironment

Tags: beamer, errors, fragile

I would like to have the title and the subtitle of my `beamer` slides to be the "current" section and subsection respectively - just like in the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{fr}{ 
        \begin{frame}{\insertsectionhead}{\insertsubsectionhead}
    }{
        \end{frame}
    }


\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{a}

\begin{fr}
    bla
\end{fr}

\subsection{b}
\begin{fr}
    blo
\end{fr}

\end{document}
```

However, when I change the line

```
\begin{frame}{\insertsectionhead}{\insertsubsectionhead}
```

to

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{\insertsectionhead}{\insertsubsectionhead}
```

(adding the `[fragile]`), I get the error "`File ended while scanning use of \next`". I found out that the solution would usually be not to indent the `\end{frame}` except that I don't have any control over that in my situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the indentation (it was, some time ago, but the code changed so now it is not important). The thing is that when you start a `fragile` frame, `beamer` looks for the exact string `\` `e` `n` `d` `{` `f` `r` `a` `m` `e` `}`, which is never found in the file, so you get a `File ended` error. Even [comments after the `\end{frame}` are not allowed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415031/134574).

However, `beamer` allows you to define verbatim (`fragile`) environments with different names as long as you tell it what is that name. For that you use the `environment` option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{fr}[1][]{%
        \begin{frame}[environment=fr,#1]{\insertsectionhead}{\insertsubsectionhead}
    }{%
        \end{frame}
    }

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{a}

\begin{fr}
    bla
\end{fr}

\subsection{b}
\begin{fr}[fragile]
  \begin{verbatim}
    \blo\
  \end{verbatim}
\end{fr}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not a good idea to hide the frame in another environment. One big problem is that this tempts users to use `fragile` frames per default which can have all kind of surprising side effects.

Instead I suggest to automatically show the section and subsection title:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \let\insertframetitle\insertsectionhead
    \let\insertframesubtitle\insertsubsectionhead
}{}
\makeatletter
  \CheckCommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
  \renewcommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\global\let\beamer@frametitle\relax\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{a}

\begin{frame}
    bla
\end{frame}

\subsection{b}
\begin{frame}
    blo
\end{frame}

\section{B}
\subsection{c}

\begin{frame}
    bla
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```